# Convergence of a sum to $e^{-1/2}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I have this sum:
$\displaystyle \sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-m} \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k}{k!} \exp \left(\frac{3 (m+k)-2 (m+k)^2}{n}\right)$.
I have some suspicion that it converges to $e ^{-1/2}$ for all $ m=1,2....$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$; but failed to prove that. Any help?

Comment: That is a pretty big suspicion. Is there anything similar to this thing that converges to anything known? alternatively the a book on summation of series might already have this in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is true.

Let $S_{-1} = 0$ and $S_n$ be the partial sum $\displaystyle\;\;\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}(-\frac12)^k\;\;$ for $n \ge 0$.
Let $\alpha_{n,k}$ be the double sequence defined by

$$\alpha_{n,k} = \begin{cases}
\exp\left(\frac{3(m+k)-2(m+k)^2}{n}\right), & 0 \le k \le \frac{n}{2} - m\\
\\
0, & k > \frac{n}{2} - m.
\end{cases}$$

For each $n$, the $n^{th}$ entry of the sequence we are interested in can be rewritten as

$$
\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-m} \frac{1}{k!}(-\frac12)^k \alpha_{n,k} =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (S_k - S_{k-1})\alpha_{n,k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} S_k (\alpha_{n,k} - \alpha_{n,k+1})$$

As long as $m > \frac14$, it is easy to check $a_{n,k}$ is a non-negative decreasing sequence in $k$ for fixed $n$.
We have:

1. For fixed $n$, 
   $\displaystyle\quad\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |\alpha_{n,k} - \alpha_{n,k+1}| = \alpha_{n,0} = 
   e^{(3m-2m^2)/n} \le \max( e^{3m-2m^2}, 1 ) < \infty.$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\alpha_{n,k} - \alpha_{n,k+1})
      =\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,0} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{(3m-2m^2)/n} = 1.$
3. For fixed $k$, $\displaystyle\quad\lim_{n\to\infty} (\alpha_{n,k}-\alpha_{n,k+1}) = 1 - 1 = 0.$

The double sequence $\alpha_{n,k}-\alpha_{n,k+1}$ satisfies the conditions for
[Silverman-Toeplitz theorem](http://planetmath.org/silvermantoeplitztheorem) and hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}S_k(\alpha_{n,k}-\alpha_{n,k+1}) = \lim_{k\to\infty} S_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}(-\frac12)^k = e^{-1/2}$$

***Notes***

Using Silverman-Toeplitz is not the most efficient way to prove the statement. There is a theorem

> **Dominated convergence theorem for series**
>
> Let $\beta_{n,k}$ be a double sequence and $b_k$, $d_k$ be two sequences such that
>
> 1. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \beta_{n,k} = b_k$ exists for every $k$.
> 2. For every $n$ and $k$, $|\beta_{n,k}| < d_k$ and $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k} d_k < \infty$.
>
> i.e. the rows of the double sequence $\beta_{n,k}$ are dominated by a single
>   non-negative sequence $d_k$ which has finite sum. Then
>
> $$\sum_{k} b_k = \sum_{k} \lim_{n\to\infty} \beta_{n,k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k}\beta_{n,k}$$

One can verify

$$\begin{align}
\beta_{n,k} = & \frac{1}{k!}(-\frac12)^k \alpha_{n,k}\\
b_k = & \frac{1}{k!}(-\frac12)^k\\
d_k = & \frac{1}{k! 2^k} \max( e^{3m-2m^2}, 1 )
\end{align}
$$
satisfies above condition for "DCT for series" and the statement follows immediately.
I can't find any wiki page for this "DCT for series" but here is a [proof](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~krieger/analysisresults.pdf) I find online.

Comment: Thanks Achille! Very neat!

Comment: two comments:(1) Concerning the use of DCT, we considered $m$ as a given number. Don't we have to worry about the case of $m$ depending on $n$. For example $m=n/2$, in that case, it is not true anymore that $\beta_{n,k} \rightarrow b_k$ since $\beta_{n,k} \rightarrow 0$ . Recall that $k$ goes from $0$ to $n/2 -m$. (2) In defining $d_k$, is it $ \frac{1}{k! 2^k} \max( e^{2m-3m^2}, 1 )$ or $  \frac{(-1/2)^k}{k!} \max( e^{2m-3m^2}, 1 )$. Thanking you!

Comment: 1) If $m$ indeed depends on $n$, then this will become a different problem. However, that isn't the case and once $m$ is given, it only affect the definition of $\alpha_{n,k}$. 2) d_k needs to be a non-negative sequence and it is $\frac{1}{k!2^k} \max(e^{2m-3m^2},1)$. The situation is similar to that in [Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), you need a non-negative sequence/function to dominated others so that one can exchange the order of taking limit and summation/integration.

Comment: I thought it would not affect the reasoning, so I shared half of the problem then. Here  is my full problem $P\left[X=k\right]= \frac{{{\rm (}{{\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2}}}}{\rm )}}^k}{k{\rm !}}\sum^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{{\rm 2}}{\rm -}k\right\rfloor }_{r{\rm =0}}{\frac{{\left({\rm -}{{\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2}}}}\right)}^r}{r{\rm !}}e^{\frac{3(r+k)-2{(r+k)}^2}{n}}}$. I want to show that $X$ converges to a Poisson (1/2). . I calculated the 8 first moments of $X$ and I found that all of them converge to those of a Poisson (1/2) hence my suspicion.

Comment: Find a typo in the $2^{nd}$ part of my answer, $d_k$ should be $\frac{1}{k! 2^k}\max(e^{3m-2m^2},1)$. About the problem of $X$ converges to Poisson(1/2). What we have shown is some sort of point-wise convergence. The proof can probably be extended to expectation value of any $f(X)$ where $f(x)$ falls to zero fast enough for large $x$. However, to really prove $X$ converge to Poisson(1/2), we need a proof of uniform convergence. I don't think there is any nice theorem one can directly use.